# Pivot data from multiple column values using R

Tags: r

I have a very large table somewhat similar to the one described below.

```
RF1 <- structure(list(FullCloneName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("010.4279.5G6", "010.X105732.87-272-7B6.B10", 
"1068.Z32346.20H4.9.8", "1100.2868.6A1.E2", "1100.2990.16E9.H6", 
"1100.3113.11A6.F1", "1100.3114.16H1.F11", "1100.3115.14F11.H4", 
"1100.3115.19A9.F10", "1100.3117.2F7.B11", "1100.Z78346.13E8.C10", 
"1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4", "1100.Z78347.18C6.B11"), class = "factor"), 
Domain = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L 
), .Label = c("VH", "VK"), class = "factor"), FieldName = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("HeavyChainObservedMass1", 
"HeavyChainObservedMass2", "HeavyChainRelativeAbundance1", 
"HeavyChainRelativeAbundance2", "LightChainObservedMass1", 
"LightChainRelativeAbundance1"), class = "factor"), ResultValue = c(23838L, 
100L, 49057L, 49185L, 82L, 18L, 24219L, 100L, 49191L, 100L, 
23787L, 50108L, 24218L, 100L, 49421L, 100L, 24349L, 24131L, 
23911L, 24197L, 24247L, 24345L, 23925L, 23675L, 23676L, 23675L, 
100L, 23675L, 100L, 23675L, 100L, 49828L, 49829L, 100L, 49830L, 
100L, 49830L, 100L, 23850L)), .Names = c("FullCloneName", 
"Domain", "FieldName", "ResultValue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L))

library(reshape2)
pivotRF1 <- dcast(RF1, FullCloneName + Domain ~ FieldName)
```

I am trying to pivot the data but, couldn't. Please Advice!

Comment: `dcast(RF, FCN + Test ~ FN)` ?

Comment: With tidyr, `RF %>% spread(FN, ResultValue)`

Comment: Hi @rawr, for the example data your solution worked like a charm. But when I use the same type of data in real time, i still face the issue. Is there any way I can share the partial real time data with you to check at your end?

Comment: Is it possible that there's an error in your input data? Check line(s) 24 and 25. One should be VH or from a different `FieldName`? To check for further mistakes, see `RF1[duplicated(RF1[, 1:3]), ]`.

Comment: Yes there is and thank you for directing me at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistakes in your dataset. Once you make sure each value corresponds to one combination of variables, you should be good to go.

For instance, see

```
> RF1[duplicated(RF1[, 1:3]), ]
            FullCloneName Domain                    FieldName ResultValue
25 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK      LightChainObservedMass1       23676
26 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK      LightChainObservedMass1       23675
28 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK      LightChainObservedMass1       23675
29 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK LightChainRelativeAbundance1         100
30 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK      LightChainObservedMass1       23675
31 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VK LightChainRelativeAbundance1         100
33 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VH      HeavyChainObservedMass1       49829
35 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VH      HeavyChainObservedMass1       49830
36 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VH HeavyChainRelativeAbundance1         100
37 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VH      HeavyChainObservedMass1       49830
38 1100.Z78346.18G2.F3.G4     VH HeavyChainRelativeAbundance1         100
```

Notice that lines 25, 26, 27, 30 are nearly identical (coming from same `FieldName` and `Domain`. Same for lines 29 and 31 and so on...

The method proposed by @rawr should work.

```
> xy <- data.frame(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4),
+                  var2 = rep(letters[1:6], each = 2),
+                  var3 = rep(1:2, times = 6),
+                  value = round(rchisq(12, df = 20)))

> xy
   var1 var2 var3 value
1     A    a    1    17
2     A    a    2    22
3     A    b    1     9
4     A    b    2    21
5     B    c    1    21
6     B    c    2    10
7     B    d    1     9
8     B    d    2    29
9     C    e    1    24
10    C    e    2    20
11    C    f    1    16
12    C    f    2    18

> dcast(xy, var1 + var2 ~ var3)
  var1 var2  1  2
1    A    a 17 22
2    A    b  9 21
3    B    c 21 10
4    B    d  9 29
5    C    e 24 20
6    C    f 16 18
```